# Can the Mass Effect 3 Omega DLC side quests be completed after the expansion is concluded?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I hate having "active" missions in my journal which I can't complete. Thankfully many of the side missions in Mass Effect 3 can be completed for a few credits from the specter room on the citadel. Not sure if that's the case for the Omega DLC side missions.

I didn't complete the Mass Effect 3 Omega DLC side quests:

- Omega: Assist the Hacker
- Omega: Assist the Mechanic

Is there anyway to complete them without replaying the Omega DLC? Other than the Meticulous Achievement do the missions grant anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon completing the Omega DLC there is actually no way back, plus those side quests are completed during the missions.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I guess they're stuck open in my journal then. :)